# Removing Emojis from string

Tags: python, string, twitter, nlp

Im doing some work with twitter, and a lot of the tweets look like

> measles \xd2@theblackpenseur: gonorrhea rt @kylegotjokes: aids rt \xd2@cache___: my head itching so bad ?\xd3

I think the `\xd2` bits are Emojis (though I may be wrong and would appreciate being corrected).

How can I remove these from a string while keeping the string intact?

Comment: google says those bits are an accented capital O (d2 and d3 are just different accents) but that doesn't seem right either. regardless, do you happen to know of the string you have is a unicode string or is that the literal string that is coming back? ie is it `u'\xd2'` (which is actually the character) or `r'\xd2'` (which is a string with 4 separate characters)

Comment: Could you provide something like a screenshot in order to show the displayed version of the tweet you quoted in your question. If we could compare the string and its displayed representation we might be able to dig deeper into your problem. A list of emojis and their UTF-8 representation can be found [here](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how much you want to clean your data, you could use

```
>>> import string
>>> tweet = 'measles \xd2@theblackpenseur: gonorrhea rt @kylegotjokes: aids rt \xd2@cache___: my head itching so bad ?\xd3'
>>> filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, tweet)
'measles @theblackpenseur: gonorrhea rt @kylegotjokes: aids rt @cache___: my head itching so bad ?'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound like a bit of self promoting (more given how old this question is) but I have a Python library that can do that (among other things). The library is [cucco](https://github.com/davidmogar/cucco) and basically you would do something like:

```
from cucco import Cucco
cucco = Cucco()
cucco.remove_stop_words('Your text')
```